# Formatting time from XML in UTC Format

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem loading XML that I receive from the program on the server, namely, the server loads UTC time, and I get time from Excel, now I need an XML that generates the time to be (one hour in summer) and (two hours shifted in winter ). Is it possible to put some how in my part of code before somebody converts XML to move all the time in an hour back? (UTC time)

This is my code:

```
  private void buttonSaveXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            //settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            settings.Indent = true;

            XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(PATH, settings);

            xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Event_Information");
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Data_Set_Type", "REPLACE");

            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Service");
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", "LeuTV");
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Event");
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Start", row.Cells[0].Value + " " + row.Cells[1].Value);
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("end-time", (string)row.Cells[2].Value);
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("short-event-descriptor");
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Language", "deu");
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Name");
                    xmlWriter.WriteString((string)row.Cells[3].Value);
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("extended-event-descriptor");
                    xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Language", "deu");
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Text");
                    xmlWriter.WriteString((string)row.Cells[4].Value);
                    xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement();
                }
            }
            xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
            xmlWriter.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully!!");
        }
```

these two lines of code set me start and end time, which I would now move for an hour back to UTC, if that's possible?

```
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Start", row.Cells[0].Value + " " + row.Cells[1].Value);
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("end-time", (string)row.Cells[2].Value);
```

thank you very much for everyone

Comment: So large parts of your question are irrelevant, and you're missing crucial details. If I understand correctly, your question is how can I take a datetime string in format "xxxxxxxx" and subtract an hour from it and then represent it back in the same format as before. Is this correct? If so, what's the datetime string?

Comment: From (string)row.Cells[2].Value To : row.Cells[2].Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz")

Comment: @spender that you are right, here are the data   xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Start", row.Cells[0].Value + " " + row.Cells[1].Value);
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("end-time", (string)row.Cells[2].Value);